# What exactly is the diagonal subgroup of a group?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, mathematical-physics

In specific consider the example of $SU(2)_a \times SU(2)_b$. What is the definition of the diagonal subgroup and how can one construct it from the generators of the group (or its algebra)?

This question is motivated by a procedure that physicists make called "topological twisting". A reference is the following one [here](http://www-fp.usc.es/theory/labastida/papers/twist.pdf) and you can see how the authors take this diagonal subgroup in the end of page 1 and the beginning of page 2.

Comment: If $G=G_1\times G_1$ is the cartesian product of a group $G_1$ with itself, the diagonal subgroup is the subset of $G$ of the form $\{(g,g)\,:\,g\in G_1\}$.

Comment: But if the product involves different groups? And how can you see this in the level of the group generators or algebra generators (assume the group is Lie)

Comment: Apologies for resurrecting this, but @Marion, did you ever get a response to your question, i.e. what is the diagonal subgroup of a product of two distinct groups $G_{1} \times G_{2}$?